# Creation of Parse Object for pointer using Xamarin and Android

Tags: java, android, object, parse-platform, xamarin

I am working for android parse.com, i have Xamarin code for the same application in which i am  making parse object in _User class with following code:

```
if (btnEditSave.Title.ToLower () == "editing") {
                SetAsEditable ();
                if (user.ContainsKey ("inform") == false) {
                    user ["inform"] = ParseObject.Create ("UserInfo");
                }
```

Now i want to apply same functionality in my android side. Can any one please change it according to android Java format. I am trying the following code but it is not working, giving error on ["inform"] to be undefined type before Running.

```
if (user.containsKey ("inform") == false) {
        user ["inform"] = ParseObject.create ("UserInfo");
    }
```

Comment: Should this `user ["info"]` be `user ["inform"]`?

Comment: Are you confusing java with javascript?

Comment: I want same functionality in Java. Basically the first code which i have paste above is from Xamarin for Ios. So kindly if u know plx help me out here.